# Visual workflow Page layout

Tags: page-layout, visual-workflow, visual

Is it possible to change the Page layout on Visual workflow or customize if so any help regarding how to do is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> UI of the visual flow can be customised if it is included in the
>   Visualforce page.

For more details check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_customize_runtime_ui.htm